# How do I merge 2 json files?

Tags: jq

file1:

```
{
    "status": {
        "errorCode": 0,
        "recordsTotal": 6,
        "recordsInResponse": 2
    },
    "records": [
        {
            "itemID": 128,
            "name": "foo barn"
        },
        {
            "itemID": 64,
            "name": "fee fom"
        }
    ]
}
```

file2:

```
{
    "status": {
        "errorCode": 0,
        "recordsTotal": 6,
        "recordsInResponse": 2
    },
    "records": [
        {
            "itemID": 32,
            "name": "pim pom"
        },
        {
            "itemID": 256,
            "name": "ping pong"
        }
    ]
}
```

wanted:

```
"records": [ // records array is not needed, having just items iterated is fine as well.
    {
        "itemID": 128,
        "name": "foo barn"
    },
    {
        "itemID": 64,
        "name": "fee fom"
    },
    {
        "itemID": 32,
        "name": "pim pom"
    },
    {
        "itemID": 256,
        "name": "ping pong"
    }
]
```

From what I have tried, I have dismissed filtering the records, focused on only combining the files.
I'm not very knowlegable with `jq`. I got the nearest results with:

- `jq -s '.[0] += .[1]'`
- `jq -s '.[0] |= . + .[1]'`

How do I merge 2 json files, probably with `jq`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid creating an initial array with `inputs`.

**(A) If you just want the objects**

```
jq -n 'inputs | .records[]'
```

Result:

```
{
  "itemID": 128,
  "name": "foo barn"
}
{
  "itemID": 64,
  "name": "fee fom"
}
{
  "itemID": 32,
  "name": "pim pom"
}
{
  "itemID": 256,
  "name": "ping pong"
}
```

**(B) If you want the objects in an array**

```
jq -n 'reduce inputs as $in ([]; . += ($in.records))'
```

Result:

```
[
  {
    "itemID": 128,
    "name": "foo barn"
  },
  {
    "itemID": 64,
    "name": "fee fom"
  },
  {
    "itemID": 32,
    "name": "pim pom"
  },
  {
    "itemID": 256,
    "name": "ping pong"
  }
]
```

**(C) If you want the objects in an array named "records"**

```
jq -n 'reduce inputs as $in ({}; .["records"] += ($in.records))'
```

Result:

```
{
  "records": [
    {
      "itemID": 128,
      "name": "foo barn"
    },
    {
      "itemID": 64,
      "name": "fee fom"
    },
    {
      "itemID": 32,
      "name": "pim pom"
    },
    {
      "itemID": 256,
      "name": "ping pong"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I have encountered this with jq before, with A, why are the objects not coma separated?

Comment: Why is the `-n` flag needed? Every other possible solution I have seen uses the `-s` flag instead. "Don't read any input at all!" in the manpages makes it somewhat more confusing, though it mentions it allows to "construct JSON data from scratch".

Comment: (A) isn't json. So maybe the best answer is to turn the question around. Why *would* the objects be comma separated?

Comment: Peter Koppstein's ["A Stream oriented Introduction to jq"](https://github.com/pkoppstein/jq/wiki/A-Stream-oriented-Introduction-to-jq#on-the-importance-of-inputs) explains why you might prefer a solution using `inputs` to one that uses `-s`.

Comment: You use `-n` to avoid losing the first entity.

Comment: (A) - Didn't know that, what makes json json?

Comment: (A) has four valid json objects. The collection of all four together is valid json only if they are in an array; then they would be comma separated. What `inputs` is doing, as I understand it, is going json entity by json entity. In (A) it puts out the objects one at a time rather than collecting them. In (B) and (C) we tell jq to collect the objects in arrays. The Koppstein article helps here; the [JSON definition](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) helps too.

Answer (score 2):

Use `-s` to create one array from both the files, than use `.[0]` and `.[1]` to get each file's structure.

```
jq -s '.[0].records + .[1].records' file1 file2
```

To include the toplevel key, wrap the expression to an object:

```
jq -s '{records: (.[0].records + .[1].records)}' file1 file2
```